# How to detect if delete button UItableviewcell was hidden?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have a view that contains a UITableView.
I'm able to show the delete button on the cell when the user swipes.

If the user touches the delete button a method will be triggered (this works fine).
But if the user decides to not to delete the cell and he touches anywhere in the view to hide the delete button.

How can I detect that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user taps outside the delete mark in a cell, your program should receive a call to `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:` on the table view delegate.

Answer (score 3):

`[UITableViewCell showingDeleteConfirmation]`

or

`[UITableViewCell willTransitionToState:]` with `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask` as parameter

Answer (score 1):

In your UITableViewCell subclass implement the willTransitionToState: method.  This method is invoked by the UITableView when the cell is being transitioned to/from the edit state.

In your implementation of the class you will need to conditionally check the value of the mask parameter passed into the method to determine what state the cell is transitioning to/from.  Possible values for the mask are...

```
enum {
    UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask                     = 0,
    UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask          = 1 << 0,
    UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask   = 1 << 1
};
```

In your case you will want to watch for transitions to the UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask so your implementation will be as follows...

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
    if (state == UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask) {
        // User has switched back to default state...
        // ...
    }
}
```