# Be notified when a UITableViewCell swipe delete is cancelled in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, hidden

I'm using willTransitionToState which notifies me when the right hand delete button is shown. However, this method is not called when the delete is cancelled by tapping outside the cell area. I've also tried tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath.

The answers found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632162/how-to-detect-if-delete-button-uitableviewcell-was-hidden) question don't work in iOS 7.

Comment: I have the same need. It seems my auto-layout positions gets adjusted when the Delete button is visible, but then when canceled, it doesn't revert back to the previous layout! Only if I grab a gripper re-ordering control does it get a layoutSubviews call. Annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for iOS 7 (not for iOS 6). The iOS 6 solution is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632162/how-to-detect-if-delete-button-uitableviewcell-was-hidden).

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self detectDeleteButtonState];

    // it takes some time for delete button to disappear
    [self performSelector:@selector(detectDeleteButtonState) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0]; 
}

- (void)detectDeleteButtonState
{
    BOOL isDeleteButtonPresent = [self isDeleteButtonPresent:self.subviews];
    if (isDeleteButtonPresent) {
        NSLog(@"delete button is shown");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"delete button is gone");
    }
}

-(BOOL)isDeleteButtonPresent:(NSArray*)subviews
{
    for (UIView *subview in subviews)
    {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"])
        {
           return [subview isHidden] == NO;
        }
        if([subview.subviews count] > 0){
           return [self isDeleteButtonPresent:subview.subviews];
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```